# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I got an error with this code:

```
import PIL.ImageOps
inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
```

The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 32, in <module>
    inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(denoise)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageOps.py", line 367, in invert
    return _lut(image, lut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageOps.py", line 48, in _lut
    if image.mode == "P":
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The line of code you post does not match your traceback. Please edit your question to include your actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Exception is raised if you try to do [`ImageOps.invert`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.invert) on a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from PIL import ImageOps
>>> ImageOps.invert(np.ones((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

To solve this issue you need to convert it to an `Image`:

```
>>> img = Image.fromarray(np.ones((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8))  # RGB image
>>> ImageOps.invert(img)
# works
```

Comment: `TypeError: fromarray() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'`